find all the separated regions shown in the right figure, and calculate the area of each of them
I have the matlab code of using gauss random field equation, which generates two-phase composites, and I can get the boundary of it. I want to find all the separated regions, shown in the black and white color in the right figure, and I want to calculate the area of them. I struggled a lot and can not find a way to do that, is there anyone who can give some advise or help? thanks
enter image description here
here is the matlab code
clear; format short e;

rng('shuffle');

%% Calculate

export = 1; % Whether or not to save data for ABAQUS

N = 1000; % number of waves to sum
mesh_size = 301; % coarseness of pattern
max_phi = 2*pi; % maximum phase shift
pct_stiff = 0.57; % fraction of material representing hard phase
lambda = 0.320; % characteristic wavelength (mm)
sample_size = 3.5 ; % characteristic length of volume (mm)

% Generate physical coordinates
x = linspace(-sample_size/2,sample_size/2,mesh_size);
y = linspace(-sample_size/2,sample_size/2,mesh_size);

% Create 3D coordinate matrices
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x, y);
phase = zeros(size(X));

for n=1:N
    % Generate random phase shift
    rand_phase = max_phi * rand(1,1);
    % Generate random vector
    rand_theta = 2 * pi * rand(1,1);
    rand_vec = [cos(rand_theta) sin(rand_theta)];
    % Dot direction vector with coordinate matrices
    vec = X*rand_vec(1) + Y*rand_vec(2);
    % Update the continuos phase field with new wave function
    phase = phase + sqrt(2/N)*cos(2*pi/lambda*vec + rand_phase);
end

%% Threshold

% Allocate space for new binary matrix
biphase = phase;
% Find average of all phase data
val_avg = mean(biphase,'all');
% Find standard deviation of all phase data
val_std = std(biphase,0,'all');
% Find the value at which the population splits into desired proportions
split = val_avg - sqrt(2) * erfinv((pct_stiff-0.5) * 2) * val_std;
% Apply threshold
biphase(phase>=split) = 1;
biphase(phase<split) = 0;

[B,L] = bwboundaries(biphase,'holes');
figure(2)
imshow(biphase)
hold on
for k = 1:length(B)
   boundary = B{k};
   plot(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1), 'r', 'LineWidth', 2)
end
hold off

%% Make coordinate output file

indx = 0;
data_out = zeros(max(cellfun('size',B,1)),2*length(B));
for k = 1:length(B)
   boundary = B{k};
   xdat = X(1,boundary(:,2))';
   ydat = -Y(boundary(:,1),1);
   data_out(1:length(boundary(:,1)),indx*2+1:indx*2+2) = [xdat, ydat];
   indx = indx + 1;
end
   
if export
    csvwrite('boundary_coordinates.csv', data_out);
end

I would like to find all the separated regions and calculate the area of each of them.

I would suggest using bwlabel on biphase. Then you can count the number of pixels with each label.
